# Finite sets and principle of excluded middle

Tags: logic, axiom-of-choice, foundations, topos-theory

This question is about the principle of excluded middle and its relation to the axiom of choice on finite sets.

I am new to the principle of excluded middle and I was reading it on nLab and Wikipedia. Intuitively, it is saying that any truth value can only be true or false.

https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/excluded+middle

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_excluded_middle

In nLab, it states the Diaconescu-Goodman-Myhill theorem. I kind of understand the statement in the theorem, but I don't understand the proof... Wikipedia also state the theorem in a different way, but I also don't quite understand it. I am going to state the theorem and the proof as in nLab below because it puzzles me more:

**Diaconescu-Goodman-Myhill theorem:**
The following statements are equivalent.

1. The principle of excluded middle.
2. Finitely indexed sets are projective (in fact, it suffices 2-indexed sets to be projective).
3. Finite sets are choice (in fact, it suffices for 2 to be choice).

Here, a set $A$ is finite or finitely-indexed (respectively) if, for some natural number $n$, there is a bijection or surjection (respectively) $\{0,…,n−1\} \rightarrow A$.

*Proof:*
If $p$ is a truth value, then divide $\{0,1\}$ by the equivalence relation where $0 \equiv 1$ iff $p$ holds. Then we have a surjection $2 \rightarrow A$, whose domain is $2$ (and in particular, finite), and whose codomain $A$ is finitely-indexed. But this surjection splits iff $p$ is true or false, so if either $2$ is choice or $2$-indexed sets are projective, then PEM holds.

On the other hand, if PEM holds, then we can show by induction that if $A$ and $B$ are choice, so is $A\coprod B$ (add details). Thus, all finite sets are choice. Now if $n \rightarrow A$ is a surjection, exhibiting $A$ as finitely indexed, it has a section $A \rightarrow n$. Since a finite set is always projective, and any retract of a projective object is projective, this shows that $A$ is projective. $\blacksquare$

What I don't understand:

- What is $A$? Is it $A = \{[x]: x \in \{0,1\} \wedge p\}$. My set notation may be a bit off; please correct me if there is something wrong.
- Is the surjection from $2$ to $A$ define as $x \mapsto [x]$? Is $p$ playing any role in defining this map?
- What does it mean that $A$ is finitely-indexed?
- What is the $2$-indexed set? Is it $A$?
- How do we show that if $A$ and $B$ are choice, then $A \coprod B$ is also choice.
- The previous bullet point then implies that all finite sets are choice. Is it because all finite sets are disjoint union of some smaller sets? Then what is the base case in the induction? Is it the set $2$? How do we prove that $2$ is choice with PEM?
- If $n \rightarrow A$ is a surjection, it has a section $A \rightarrow n$? It is because $n$ is finite and is a choice, hence we can invoke the axiom of choice?
- Why is a finite set always projective?

I think the biggest problem I am facing is that I don't see the big picture of the proof. I guess it is because I am not familiar with mathematics without the excluded middle. It is such a strange world.

Comment: It should be noted that nLab is writing this proof in the context of a topos.

Comment: I don't know much about topos... Does this version of the theorem hold in a more naive context.

Comment: Yes, I think the questions you are asking can be answered without referring to the technicalities of topoi. Personally, I feel that nLab's proof is a bit sloppy. You might find Wikipedia's proof more comprehensible (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diaconescu%27s_theorem).

Comment: Half of your questions are the same, and can be answered by the first sentence in the proof.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I think that comment could be seen as rude. You might want to remove it based on the [community guidelines](https://math.stackexchange.com/conduct)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, some of the terminology they use such as "[truth value](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/truth+value)", are defined for arbitrary topoi as I think they meant for this argument to work in any topos. In the category of sets, a truth value by nLab's definition is simply a function $p:1\to \Omega$ where $\Omega$ is a [subobject classifier](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/subobject+classifier) (here $1=\{0\}$). You can think of $\Omega$ as being the set of truth values and $p$ as being a function which picks out one of those truth values. So when they say $0\equiv 1$ iff $p$ holds, what they mean is $0\equiv 1$ if $p(0)=true$ and $0\not\equiv 1$ if $p(0)=false$ (a priori we cannot say "$p(0)=true$ or $p(0)=false$"). I will attempt to answer your questions in the order you listed them.

- Yes, $A=\{[x]\mid x\in\{0,1\}\}$ where $[x]$ is the equivalence class of $x$. They should have made this more clear in my opinion.
- Yes, the surjection is $x\mapsto[x]$. This map does in some sense depend of $p$ since the codomain of the surjection depends on $p$, but that's it.
- They state what finitely-indexed means earlier: "Here, a set $A$ is finitely-indexed if, for some natural number $n$, there is a surjection $\{0,\ldots,n-1\}\to A$."
- A set is $2$-indexed if it is indexed by $2$, i.e. there exists a surjection $\{0,1\}\to A$. In the proof, $A$ is $2$-indexed.
- Suppose $A$ and $B$ are choice and let $R$ be an entire relation from a set $S$ to $A\sqcup B$. Let
  $$S_1=\{x\in S\mid \exists y\in A,\ (x,y)\in R\}$$
  $$R_1=\{(x,y)\in R\mid x\in S_1\land y\in A\}$$
  $$S_2=S\setminus S_1$$
  $$R_2=\{(x,y)\in R\mid x\in S_2\}$$
  Then $R_1$ is an entire relation from $S_1$ to $A$ and $R_2$ is an entire relation from $S_2$ to $B$, so by assumption, there exist functions $f_1:S_1\to A$ and $f_2:S_2\to B$ such that $f_1\subseteq R_1$ and $f_2\subseteq R_2$. Then $f_1\cup f_2$ defines a function from $S_1\cup S_2$ to $A\sqcup B$ with $f_1\cup f_2\subseteq R$. Finally, by the principle of excluded middle, $S_1\cup S_2=S$, from which we conclude that $A\sqcup B$ is choice.
- The previous bullet implies that all finite sets are choice by simple induction since $\{0,\ldots,n-1\}$ is the disjoint union of $\{0,\ldots,n-2\}$ and $\{n-1\}$ for all $n\geq 2$. The base case would be the set $0=\emptyset$ and sets in bijection with $1=\{0\}$. Once the previous bullet has been proven, you shouldn't need excluded middle for this inductive argument.
- This simply uses what was previously established. Since the map $n\to A$ is surjective, the inverse relation from $A$ to $n$ is an entire relation. And because $n$ is finite and we established that finite sets are choice, this entire relation has a subset which is a function $A\to n$ and which must therefore be a section of the original function $n\to A$.
- This is a simple proof by induction on $\{0,\ldots,n-1\}$. I suggest you try it as an exercise instead of me proving it for you.

Let me know if you need any additional clarification on any points.

Comment: Wait, a truth value is not a function $1 \to 2$. Rather, a truth value is a subset of $1 = \{\heartsuit\}$. One such subset is $\emptyset$, another is $\{\heartsuit\}$, and potentially these two options are not all possibilities. The set $A$ is constructed as the quotient $A/R$, where $R$ is the smallest equivalence relation which contains the set $X = \{ (0,1) | p \}$. This set $X$ is a subset of $2 \times 2$ which contains $(0,1)$ iff $p$ holds.

Comment: Other than that, thank you for the detailed write-up! :-)

Comment: @IngoBlechschmidt Sorry, can you phrase it in a different way? I don't quite understand what you are trying to say. What I understood: a truth value $p$ is an element of the power set $\mathcal{P}(1)$. What I don't understand: if $p \in \mathcal{P}(1)$, is it the same as how it was stated in the answer $p:1 \rightarrow 2$? What is $A$ explicitly; is it stated as before $A = \{[x] | x \in \{0,1\}\}$?

Comment: @IngoBlechschmidt Thank you for catching my blunder. I was trying to go by nLab's definition that a truth value is a morphism $1\to \Omega$ where $\Omega$ is a subobject classifier. In the category of sets, $\Omega=\{1,2\}$ but only if you assume classical logic, so I made a mistake there. To be correct, $\Omega$ should be the power set of $1$ as you said.

Comment: @Jerry In classical logic, there is a one-to-one correspondence between the power set of a set $X$ and the set of functions $X\to 2$, but this one-to-one correspondence need not exist when we lack excluded middle. And yes, $A$ is just the set of equivalence classes.

Comment: @Anonymous Thanks for the answer. Do you mind giving a short explanation why the power set of $X$ and the set of functions $X \rightarrow 2$ may not be in one-to-one correspondence when we lack excluded middle? I am a novice in logic, and I tried searching on the web but all I got is the exact statement without explanation. For instance, in nLab https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/power+set, it states "One can use power sets to construct function sets; the converse also works using excluded middle (or anything else that will guarantee the existence of the set of truth values)."

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructive_set_theory also kind of state the same thing: "Additionally the power set axiom implies the existence of a set of truth values. In the presence of LEM, this set exists and has two elements. In the absence of it, the set of truth values is also considered impredicative."

Comment: If the answer would be too long, I am happy to open a new question about this

Comment: Let $F$ be the set of (total) functions $X\to 2$ and let $P=\mathcal{P}(X)$. Define $\phi:F\to P$ by $\phi(f)=\{x\in X\mid f(x)=1\}$. Proving $\phi$ is surjective uses LEM. Explicitly, given $Y\subset X$ we can define a partial function $f:X\to 2$ by $f(x)=1$ if $x\in Y$ and $f(x)=0$ if $x\notin Y$. To show $f$ is total, we need to know that for all $x\in X$ either $x\in Y$ or $x\notin Y$, from which we conclude $\phi(f)=Y$. But of course, this requires LEM. To see that we cannot get around LEM, note that $\phi$ being surjective implies LEM since then the only truth values are true and false.

Comment: @Anonymous Just to clarify, the part which uses LEM is "for all $x \in X$ either $x \in Y$ or $x \notin Y$. It uses LEM because $x \in Y$ or $x \notin Y$ is true assuming LEM.

Comment: @Jerry That is correct.

Comment: @Anonymous I actually don't quite see how $\phi$ being surjective implies LEM since then the only truth values are true and false. My attempt to understanding this: Suppose $\phi: F \rightarrow P$ is surjective. Given $Y \subset X$ there exists $f \in F$ such that $\phi(f) = Y$. By the definition of $\phi$, $Y = \{x \in X | f(x) = 1\}$. This means that $f(y) = 1$ for $y \in Y$. ... ... Then how do I continue?

Comment: Since $f$ is total, $f(x) = 0$ for $x \notin Y$. Does this imply that the truth values are only true and false?? My head hurts...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109539/discussion-between-anonymous-and-jerry).

Comment: @Jerry I don't know if this was made explicit, but the role of $p$ in the construction is that the *equivalence relation* that you're taking the quotient of can be defined as $\{ (x, y) \in 2 \times 2 \mid (x = y) \lor p \}$.  And then, for example, $[0] = \{ x \in 2 \mid (x = 0) \lor p \} = \{ x \in 2 \mid (x = 0) \lor (x = 1 \land p) \}$.

Comment: @Jerry It might also help to see what the construction gives in some example of a topos where LEM does not hold.  For example, if you perform the construction in the category of presheaves on $\mathbb{R}$, and $p$ is the subobject $h_{(0,\infty)}$, then $A$ is the presheaf where $A(U) = \begin{cases} \{ 0 \}, & U \subseteq (0, \infty);\\ \{ 0, 1 \}, & \mathrm{otherwise}.\end{cases}$  It might be illuminating to check why this presheaf is not a choice object of that topos.

Comment: Thanks @DanielSchepler. Please pardon my ignorance on presheaves, do you mind saying a few more words about the example. I suppose $\mathbb{R}$ is treated as a topological space. Is $h_{(0,\infty)}$ the open interval $(0,\infty)$? The definition of the presheaf $A$ looks natural to me, but i don't fully understand how to get this definition from quotienting $\{0,1\}$ with the equivalence relation.

Comment: Yes, $\mathbb{R}$ is treated as a topological space using the usual topology (i.e. the order topology or equivalently the metric topology under the usual metric).  $h_{(0, \infty)}$ is the presheaf whose sections over $U$ are $\{ 0 \}$ if $U \subseteq (0, \infty)$ and $\emptyset$ otherwise.  This is a subobject of the final presheaf $1$, which according to the definition of the subobject classifier $\Omega$ corresponds to a morphism $1 \to \Omega$ - and that, in turn, is equivalent to a member of the section set $\Omega(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: As for the relation of my presentation of $A$ with the construction as the quotient of an equivalence relation - that follows from the fact that *in a presheaf category* quotients of equivalence relations can be taken on a "point by point basis": $(\mathscr{F} / {\equiv})(U) \simeq \mathscr{F}(U) / {\equiv}(U)$.  And in this case, $\mathscr{F}(U) = \{ 0, 1 \}$ for every $U$; and ${\equiv}(U) = \{ (0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1) \}$ when $U \subseteq (0, \infty)$ and ${\equiv}(U) = \{ (0, 0), (1, 1) \}$ otherwise.

Comment: @DanielSchepler I'm completely lost. Is there somewhere I can read more about this example?

Comment: I'm not certain if this specific example would be anywhere - and I'm not certain I could suggest anything for further reading other than general references on the notion of presheaves and then introductory texts on topos theory.